# How to display image from src/images without using import at the top and without using public directory in react/reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render the `star1.png` located in `src/images/` directory without using `import` at the top and without using the `public` directory.

My code:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

class App extends React.Component
{
    render(){
        let starIcon = "./images/star1.png"

        return(
            <>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
                <img src={starIcon} />
            </>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: If it's  small image maybe you could use base64 encoded version of your image ? Not sure to understand the whole point.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `import`?

Comment: @Peterrabbit my example uses a small image, however the project I am working I am with uses large images

Comment: @Andy I cannot call `import` inside components

Comment: You're importing React. Why can't you import anything else?

Comment: @Andy I mean, I cannot call `import` inside a `component` or `function` . ERROR: `An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a module`. I have explained it, I want to pass `image` as `props`.

Comment: But your code doesn't show that problem. That's why we're confused about what's going on.

Comment: @Andy please just read. I just want to keep the code simple.

Comment: But your example has no `import` other than React, and you're not passing any props to any other component, or to `App`. There's a lot of code missing from your question, and without that we can't help debug the it.

Comment: @Andy i have edited the whole question. you don't have to worry about `props`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question which is using `require`:

```
let starIcon = require("./images/star1.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question fully, but you could pass the image as a blob through props and set that blob as the source of the image.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the prod build I think because when you created a build asset directory will not copy.

Solutions:

1. You can import it'll be added to the bundle it'll work
2. You can move to the public it'll also be added in the build/dist directory
3. **You can manually/automatically copy assets to the build/dist directory.**

The last solution you are looking I think.